# Losing character spaces in outlook 2010 and gmail messages from php output

Tags: php, outlook, gmail

Im having a strange problem and Im wondering if anyone here has seen this occur.

Im generating some email from a php script. Standard stuff, call data from a table, put it in a message, call the mail function. The headers are set to render html and tables output as expected in the email. When I echo my $message variable to the screen, the output is flawless. The record in the table is the way it should be as well. However, when I get the email in gmail and my client in outlook, we get missing spaces between words, like:

VisualElements

What makes it worse is that its random, so I can have 2 lines with the same words for two different records and I will get
Visual Elements
VisualElements

I cant seem to even find a good search to throw at google for this so Im hoping someone here has seen this before.

I can paste code if you need it, but Im pretty sure it leaves my server properly (based on the browser output). If I generate that email naturally by the way, those words may be fine and other may be messed up, its very random.

Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Sorry about that, meant to include that source! I do see the error at the end and the definition here http://msg.wikidoc.info/index.php/Rejectsmtplonglines,_truncatesmtplonglines,_wrapsmtplonglines_Channel_Options

Im not sure how that applies to these short lines, unless its counting the HTML chars as well?

Heres raw email from gmail:

```
Delivered-To: xx@gmail.com
Received: by xx.xx.xx.xxwith SMTP id jf12csp233137oab;
        Sun, 9 Feb 2014 22:36:09 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.140.36.107 with SMTP id o98mr42112677qgo.25.1392014168275;
        Sun, 09 Feb 2014 22:36:08 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Received: from mta2.srv.hcvlny.cv.net (mta2.srv.hcvlny.cv.net. [167.206.4.197])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id q2si9408850qaq.99.2014.02.09.22.36.08
        for <xxxx@gmail.com>;
        Sun, 09 Feb 2014 22:36:08 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 167.206.4.197 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of DDMADatabase@danieldemarco.com) client-ip=167.206.4.197;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 167.206.4.197 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of xxxx@xxxx.com) smtp.mail=xxxx@xxxx.com
Received: from xxxx.xxxx.local
 (ool-18599ad2.static.optonline.net [24.89.154.210]) by mta2.srv.hcvlny.cv.net
 (Sun Java System Messaging Server 6.2-8.04 (built Feb 28 2007))
 with SMTP id <0N0R00I47P07ATB0@mta2.srv.hcvlny.cv.net> for
 xxx@gmail.com; Mon, 10 Feb 2014 01:36:08 -0500 (EST)
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 01:35:57 -0500
From: xxxx@xxxx.com
Subject: PO Due Date Date Missed
To: xxxx@gmail.com, xxxx@xxxx
Reply-to: xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com
Message-id: <0N0R00I48P07ATB0@mta2.srv.hcvlny.cv.net>
MIME-version: 1.0
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.6MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT
Sun-Java-System-SMTP-Warning: Lines longer than SMTP allows found and wrapped.
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:triggers.php

<html><head></head><body><table  border='1' bordercolor='#999999'width='100%'>

    <tr>

    <td ><b>Project Name</b></td>
    <td ><b>Desc</b></td>
      <td ><b>Vendor</b></td>
    <td><b>Due Date</b></td>
    </tr><tr><td>9/11 Museum Store</td><td>del 2/7</td><td>SPD IntegratedCarriers</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>9/11     MuseumStore</td><td>metal</td><td>North American Metal CraftInc</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>9/11     MuseumStore</td><td>lighting</td><td>Optolum</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>9/11Museum    Store</td><td>Glass</td><td>BearGlass</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>ADKitchenette</td><td>Installation </td><td>Walts     Woodworking</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>BeBe El Paso Perimeter </td><td>Shelfhardware</td><td>Visplay</td><td>2014-02-    07</td></tr><tr><td>BeBeScottsdale Perimeter</td><td>ShelfHardware</td><td>Visplay</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>BeBe     ShortHills Mall Perimeter</td><td>fabric wrapping</td><td>D'Orazio Upholstery</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>BeBe Short     Hills MallPerimeter</td><td>Shelfhardware</td><td>Visplay</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>Club      MonacoBroadway</td><td>install extras</td><td>Cord
    Contracting</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>Givenchy NM Bal HarbourRTW</td><td>Shelves and         Mirrors</td><td>VerrageGlass</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>Louis Vuitton - Neiman Marcus SanAntonio</td><td>Metal     fabrication</td><td>Roy Metal</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>MontblancVancouver</td><td>Cabinetry</td><td>Summit Retail     Solutions</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr><tr><td>Tommy Hilfiger Polo BlueSamples</td><td>Polo Blue Lacquer Samples</td><td>Gemini     StoreFixtures</td><td>2014-02-07</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: use the email clients view source

Comment: If you don't show an example of the raw email and "the problem" - it's pretty hard to suggest anything.

Comment: Ive added the raw email code to the question, any thoughts anyone?